# TocaEdit X360 Controller Emulator doesn't create dll when in Program Files

Tags: windows-7, gaming, game-controller

When I run `x360ce.exe` from the desktop, I see this dialog after a second or so:

[image: xinput1_3.dll was not found]

But when I put this same file in the game directory within `C:\Program Files (x86)\` and run it as administrator (right-click, select "Run as Administrator") the dll dialog never appears, and no controllers are found.

I'm assuming this is a permissions issue, but beyond saying "Run as administrator" what else can I do?

Comment: Interestingly, this works using older versions of the app. (I've tested using `2.1.2.191`)